# How do I require a file without defining it's constants on Object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I would like to require a file in Ruby without defining that file's constants on Object. Instead I would like to include them only in a module in the requiring file. For instance if I have a file foo.rb that looks like this:

```
module Foo
  def self.hello_world
    puts 'Hello, World.'
  end
end
```

A representation of the result I hope to achieve looks something like this:

```
module Bar
  require_relative './foo.rb'
end

Foo.hello_world
# NameError: uninitialized constant Foo

Bar::Foo.hello_world
# Hello, World.
```

It seems like the way things are required in Ruby, anything defined at the top level of another file will be defined as a constant on Object and thus globally available. I'm having a problem because I need something from a file that conflicts with a constant in the global namespace.

I recognize that this problem may be fundamental to Ruby, but is it possible there's some metaprogramming technique to overcome this issue?

Comment: is there any reason why you don't just reopen the namespace? `module Bar::Foo ... end`

Comment: In my case to I don’t have control over the source file of Foo. Only Bar.

Comment: there isn't a way to do this other than the class_eval solution you post in the answer. But what people commonly do, when they want to avoid making globals, is to make a single namespace and make everything else a subclass of that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the following snippet works for what I'm trying to do:

```
module Bar
  class_eval File.open('./foo.rb').read
end
```

It may be that I'm still missing something though.

Comment: Yes, it works. But that is called brute force. It is not elegant.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to access the ancestor, what you're looking for is `extend`

```
module Foo
  def hello_world
    puts 'Hello, World.'
  end
end

module Bar
  extend Foo 
end


Bar.hello_world
```

Comment: This will define the module in `Bar` **in addition to defining it in `Object`. That is not what the OP wanted.